# How to make an absolute div, inside a relative one, overflow a scrollable div

Tags: html, css

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div class="rel">
      <div>11</div>
      <div class="modal">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
.parent {
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  width: 10rem; 
  height: 100%; 
  max-height: 200px;
  border-width: 1px; 
  background-color: #6EE7B7; 
}

.rel {
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute; 
  background-color: #FCA5A5; 
  width: 14rem; 
}
```

and the output:

[image]

My question is: how can I make the div with "test" written overflow the scrollable div, and keep it attached to the relative parent. I want to make this like a floating element, with external to the scrollable div.

I searched a lot and found [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-stop-a-div-inside-a-scrollable-div-being-hidden/222959) discussion, but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it OK to add a container? I think this does what you're asking:

CSS:

```
.container {
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
.parent {
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  width: 10rem; 
  height: 100%; 
  max-height: 200px;
  border-width: 1px; 
  background-color: #6EE7B7; 
}

.rel {
  /* position: relative; */
}

.modal {
  position: absolute; 
  top:200px;
  background-color: #FCA5A5; 
  width: 14rem; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="parent">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div class="rel">
          <div>11</div>
          <div class="modal">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```